# I'm unable to get private attribute from a component to use in force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service, force-recorddata

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="boatReview" type="BoatReview__c" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="boatReviewRecord" type="BoatReview__c" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="boat" type="Boat__c"/>
     **<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" access="private"/>**
    <!--<aura:attribute name="recordError1" type="String" access="public"/>-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="boatReviewAdded" type="c:BoatReviewAdded"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="service"
                      **targetError="{!v.recordError}"**
                      targetRecord="{!v.boatReviewRecord}"
                      targetFields="{!v.boatReview}"
                      fields="Id,Name,Comment__c,Boat__c"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.onRecordUpdated}"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      />

    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="12" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:input name="title" label="Title" value="{!v.boatReview.Name}"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>

            <lightning:layoutItem size="12" padding="around-small">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-01">Description</label>
                <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.boatReview.Comment__c}" disabledCategories="FORMAT_FONT"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>

            <lightning:layoutItem size="12" class="slds-align--absolute-center">
                <lightning:button iconName="utility:save" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.onSave}"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
     <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                {!v.recordError}
            </ui:message>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

I'm getting this error :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We **cannot pass private attributes to child components**. Private components are only accessible inside that component. Not in parent nor in child. So you have to make recordError attribute public.